# React-native-elements Overlay ignores TouchableOpacity onPress function

Tags: react-native, button, overlay, touchableopacity, react-native-elements

I've put two TouchableOpacity buttons inside the Overaly form react-native-elements, and when I click on them nothing happens.

Doesn't Overlay support buttons inside of it? In the docs of the Overlay buttons are not mentioned.

```
import { Overlay } from 'react-native-elements';

toggleOverlay = () => {
     this.setState({isVisible: !this.state.isVisible});
};

                <Overlay
                    isVisible={this.state.isVisible}
                    onBackdropPress={this.toggleOverlay}
                    height="82%"
                    width= "95%"
                >

                    <View style={styles.contenedor_Botones}>

                        <View style={styles.botones_Principales}>

                            <TouchableOpacity style={styles.boton_Principal}
                                onPress={() => {
                                    this.toggleOverlay();
                                }}
                            >
                                <Text style={styles.texto_Boton}>
                                    METEREOLOGÍA
                                </Text>
                            </TouchableOpacity>

                            <TouchableOpacity style={styles.boton_Principal}
                                onPress={() => {
                                    alert("auwydau");
                                }}>
                                <Text style={styles.texto_Boton}>
                                    INFORMACIÓN ADICIONAL
                                </Text>
                            </TouchableOpacity>

                        </View>

                    </View>

                </Overlay>
```

I want to open a new Overlay when I press these buttons. Thanks for your hepl!

Comment: did you find a solution?

Comment: @schingeldi no, I just used a <Button> instead

Answer (score 0):

I had same problem only Android.

I solved the problem using `import { TouchableOpacity } from 'react-native'`.

Before I used `import { TouchableOpacity } from 'react-native-gesture-handler'`.

Answer (score 0):

For me, giving a `zIndex` to the container of my buttons did the job. In our project we have some kind of interactive videos where the interaction buttons appear on the `VideoPlayer`. For those interaction options I used a blurry View with `position: 'absolute'` and a big zIndex like `zIndex: 30`. Within this View I just added my `TouchableOpacity`s - et voilà:

```
<View
    style={{
      position: 'absolute',
      flex: 1,
      flexDirection: 'column',
      justifyContent: 'flex-end',
      paddingBottom: 50,
      bottom: 0,
      zIndex: 30,
      minHeight: Dimensions.get('window').height,
      width: Dimensions.get('window').width,
      backgroundColor: theme.colors.white_blur[3],
      display: 'flex',
    }}>
    {/* {interactions.map(item => {
      
    })} */}

    <TouchableOpacity
      onPress={() => {
        console.log('Auswahl 1..');
      }}
      style={styles.interactions}>
      <Text style={styles.interactions_text}>My interaction Btn 1</Text>
    </TouchableOpacity>
    <TouchableOpacity
      style={styles.interactions}
      onPress={() => {
        console.log('Auswahl 2..');
      }}>
      <Text style={styles.interactions_text}>
        My interaction Btn 2
      </Text>
    </TouchableOpacity>
  </View>
```

If anyone still needs help, just leave a comment with your code snippet and I'll see what I can do.